Particular case of Exponential Distribution Memorylessness
I have a dispute with my uni colleagues. There is an exercise requiring us to calculate, given an exponential distribution S, the following probability $$P(1<S<2|1<S).$$
According to them the memorylessness property of the exponential applies to this case and therefore the calculation reduces to $$P(0<S<1)$$
On the contrary, I'm against it and I think that we should use the formula $$P(1<S<2)/P(1<S).$$
What is the right interpretation?
tl;dr Is it true that, for an exponential distribution S, P(a<S<a+b|a<S)=P(0<S<b), for $b>0$, holds?

Suppose $S$ has Exponential $\lambda$ distribution. Then $P(1<S<2)=e^{-\lambda}-e^{-2\lambda}$ and $P(1<S)=e^{-\lambda}$. So $P(1<S<2)/P(1<S)=1-e^{-\lambda}=P(0<S<1)$. This is itself the memoryless property and it is just a property of the exponential function. So, when one says that it is due to the memoryless property, one is implicitly saying that the exponential distribution satisfies $P(a<S<a+b)/P(a<S)=P(0<S<b)$ we can directly say that $P(a<S<a+b|a<s)=P(0<S<b)$.
